# How to map a redux state slice to a local component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently I'm using the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    stateInProps: state.someSliceIWant
  };
};

Foo.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  stateInProps: PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo);
```

and since we can only actually map state to props, and not directly to state in my component, I'm getting around this in a hacky way by doing this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    setTimeout(() => {this.setState(this.props.stateInProps);},1);

  }
```

How should I do this properly? I've tried using different lifecycle hooks and all sorts of methods.

An interesting thing I found was that if I put setState() in mapStateToProps.... it ALMOST works.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  Foo.setState(state.someSliceIWant);
  return {
    stateInProps: state.someSliceIWant
  };
};
```

It throws a bunch of errors, but when I delete that line and webpack grinds through and the page re-renders, the state has actually been updated properly and the values are there! WHAT?! I can't figure out how to get it do that, without throwing the errors, as Redux/React itself won't allow it as best I can tell.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps() doesn't work for you?

Comment: 1. why do you want to store redux state as component state at all? 2. you can use `componentDidUpdate` for that

Comment: +1 for comment from @pergy. Is there any reason hindering you from directly using `this.props.stateInProps`? It is not recommended to copy redux state to local state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ComponentWillReceiveProps after mapping state to Props?

For instance:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The hacky way you are using, you might not able to access your `stateInProps` if it get updated in later lifecycle.

You can use something as below

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  state = {};

  componentWillMount() { this.setStateInProps(this.props); }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { this.setStateInProps(nextProps)}

  setStateInProps= (props) => this.setState(props.stateInProps)

}
```